# Finding number of relationships is very slow

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I have a `many-to-many` relationship with two `Core Data` `entities`.

[image]

A `Person` entity can be a part of many different clubs. So, when I am deleting a club I would also like to remove the relationship to all the `Person` entities. If that person entity doesn't have any other relationships to `Clubs` I will delete that from `Core Data`, if it does have other relationships I just remove the `Person` from the `Club` instead of deleting.

To check to see if the `Person` has other relationships I am using the `objectIDsForRelationshipNamed:` method and seeing if the `NSArray` count is more than 1. If it is then I remove the entity from the relationship, if it isn't, I delete it from core data.

```
for (ZSSCDPerson *person in self.items) {

    NSUInteger relationshipCount = [person objectIDsForRelationshipNamed:@"clubs"];// Slow
    NSUInteger relationshipCount2 = person.clubs.count;// Also slow
    if (relationshipCount > 1) {

        [privateClub removePersonObject:person];

    } else {

        [self.managedObjectPrivateContext deleteObject:person];

    }

}
```

**The problem**

Using `objectIDsForRelationshipNamed:` is slow. Using Instruments and `Time Profiler` I can see this. I instead used `person.clubs.count` to see how many clubs the `Person` entity was in. This is also very slow.

**Are there any other ways to check to see if an entity has more than one relationship that doesn't cause performance issues like these two methods?**

Answer (score 0):

You can specify that in your predicate. If you want to fetch the people with a number of clubs equals to a number, you can do:

```c
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"clubs.@count", 0];
```

You can find more information about predicates [here](https://realm.io/news/nspredicate-cheatsheet/). I hope it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

1. On the club you want to delete, start with using it's bulk method for removing people objects.  The set to pass in to that method would be the club.people set (or whatever you named that relationship).
2. Fetch the people objects that now don't have any clubs (using the predicate from Pedro's answer).
3. Delete the people you got in #2.

And of course, delete the club any time after step #1.

Comment: I thought from what I read using the bulk delete method is a bad idea with relationships? That is will leave things in Core Data that should have been removed?

Comment: I've never seen any issue when using an NSManagedObject's subclassed method for removing multiple objects from a relationship's set.  Is that what you are talking about?  Or are you referring to step #3?

Comment: I am meaning, what I provided is just an easy to understand example. My actual entity has about 5 relationships. When I bulk delete the Person I would need to delete all of those other relationships and objects.

Comment: Have you tried using "cascade" as the delete rule on your relationships?  I think you could do that for all of them instead of my step 1.

Comment: Yes, I use `cascade` as my delete rule. But the bulk delete `NSBatchDeleteRequest` does not take relationships into account.

Comment: I wasn't talking about NSBatchDeleteRequest.  I was referring to the method you get for free on your subclassed NSManagedObject classes for removing multiple objects from a relationship.  The delete in #3 was intended to be in a for loop.